# Regular Expression Javascript with XCode

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xcode, forms

i am trying to sieve out the username and text fields of a HTML Form loading in a web view. Previously i tried this method to narrow down the corresponding text fields that i need but it was tedious and there is no end to the computation of variables. even though i thought i listed out a lot of variables, it was still a hit and miss solution, not all website works.

```
var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']"); 
for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { 
        if ( (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'email')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'Email')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'e-mail')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'E-mail')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'emailerr')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'UID')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'uid')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'username')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'Username')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'userName')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'user_name')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'User_Name')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'User_name')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'userid')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'userID')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'UserID')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'Userid')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'ID')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'id')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'j_username')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'session_key')
        ||   (inputFields[i].getAttribute('name') == 'login_password')) {
                             inputFields[i].value = '%@';}}
```

Then i was told about RegularExpression but i wasn't very familiar with it and i read some tutorials about it but not specific to my project to try and get what it means and i piece out this code which is also a hit and miss solution. I am not even sure if i am doing it right but the code is definitely short this time for sure.

```
var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']"); 
for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { 
     regStr = /(mail|user|iden|name|id|key|login|username|email)/i; 
     searchName = inputFields[i].getAttribute('name').search(regStr);
     searchId = inputFields[i].getAttribute('id').search(regStr);
     if (!(searchName == -1) || !(searchId == -1)){ 
          inputFields[i].value = '%@';}}
```

Can someone tell me if i have done this RegularExpression correctly? i really have no idea. Some sites it works, some it doesn't. I understand that what i am searching for is configurable by developers and i won't have a 100% hit on all site, but what puzzle me is that sometime even though the term matches exactly one of my search variable it didn't work.

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Can you just show the Javascript and leave out Apple's special objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SPARTA!

Your RegExp didn't match the list of values, you provided in your looong code.

```
var opts = "email,e-mail,emailerr,uid,username,userid,id,j_username," +
    "session_key,login_password,live,liveid,live_id,live_email";
var re = new RegExp(opts.replace(/,/g, "|"), "i");
if (re.test(inputFields[i].getAttribute('name'))) {
    inputFields[i].value = '%@';
}
```

PS: You're not going to use it as some spamming utility, aren't you?

Comment: Let me try if this works, nope not for spamming utility. here is my application page on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/SignatureAccess

Comment: in my long code i was trying for everything that i can think of, in the shorter code i believe they can search for less specific terms as they were somehow like wildcards and as long as the find any of the terms in the search string it will return positive. i was counting on the regEx to help make wildcards search so i can achieve higher success rate.

Comment: tried your method, and put in into my Xcode, it isn't working, even those sites that used to work with my regEx code i did above, didn't work now.

Comment: I've missed parenthesis around if condition.

Comment: Arh!! i have been starring at your code for a long time and i can't spot anything wrong. haha! Yea now the regular sites that used to work is working now.But those that should work aren't still. from the source code of one such website(www.modelmayhem.com": "<input type="text" name="email" value="" autocomplete="off" />" it has type=text and name=email and ought to work but it aren't. Also could you explain the syntax of re.test?

Comment: Login form on `modelmayhem` is located in iframe on another domain and another protocol (https). `re.test` tests, whether certain regexp matches some string. Read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out to me. please rate my questions if you think it will be helpful to the others. =)